# How do you change hair particles into a mesh without the thickness of the hair going away?

Tags: hair

I have attempted to use the convert modifier but I am unable to make the mesh thick, like it was on the actual head. Does anyone have a way to make the hair mesh have actual thickness?

Comment: I think the closes is to make the hair into curves and then add geometry to that to make something similar

Comment: Oh yes, converting *hair > mesh > curves + bevel > mesh* works, too.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the *Particle Instance* modifier.

Model a plane/stripe or cone, subdivide it as many times as the hair particles have segments. (You can change the number of segments of the particles in *Particle Edit* mode if needed; menu: *Particle > Rekey*). Then add and apply a *Particle Instance* modifier. The result is a mesh with instantiated hair stripes. It's kinda little hair cards.

[image: particle instance modifier example]

Just be aware that this can create a huge amount of vertices/faces when you have particle children activated!

The origin of the stripe must be at the world origin and it must be placed in the direction of the Y-axis.

[image: hair stripe]