Hair Particle/ Particle System (Hair turning by user's view point)
I'm currently studying how to create a character in Blender, which requires rigging, texturing, and optimization.
I'm currently stuck with the hair particle system. I'm trying to make hair using hair particles, but the hair is rotating from my point of view. Do you know how to fix that? All I want is to anchor the hair so it doesn't overlap, glitch out, or collide with other hair particles.
I have an example of the hair I made:


Hi. That's the normal render of the hair particles in EEVEE. Cycles renders them as Rounded Ribbons or 3D Curves depending on the settings (Render tab > Curves section > Shape). If you need more control of the tilt (=rotation) of the curves you can render the particles as planes (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230306/107598). But the tilt of the particles can only manipulated with the comb and it's hard to do.
