How to reduce polycount of hair converted to mesh?
I made hair using particle system then I converted the particle system into mesh from modifiers menu. Now to give thickness to this hair I converted it to curves and beveled it, now I converted these curves to mesh again. This is the process of me getting hair particle system as a mesh.

but the face count of this mesh is too much making my pc lag. I have applied decimate modifier and remesh modifier but none of it works as it makes the hairs look completely destroyed. How can I get low face count with same or a little less detail?
I know all the parts are joined but I have checked that most faces are from hairs only.

Instead of beveled curves, you could try a simple plane with a few cuts. Add a Particle Instance modifier to the plane and make sure its orientation is correct. Here is an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/230306/107598. Apply to the modifier to create the final hair mesh. The drawback is that you cannot see the hair plane when it's perpendicular to the camera's view. And depending on how many hair particles your model has, it can still create a lot of geometry.

@Blunder I am having ~300K faces for my whole model including hair is that bad, if I want to use in threejs environment
